# Compiling variables in elisp

Tags: variables, emacs, initialization, startup

How do you compile variables in elisp that are the result of function calls?  Is it a requirement to add a `eval-when-compile` into the body of all the variables or is there someway I can ensure the same result without needing to rewrite that in all variable definitions?

The use case was compiling my local variables that change between machines.  For example,

```
(defun setup-defaults (loc)
  (when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (cond
     ((file-exists-p (expand-file-name loc "~"))
      (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name loc "~")))
     ((file-exists-p (expand-file-name loc "d:/"))
      (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name loc "d:/"))))))

(defconst my/org (setup-defaults "org"))

(defconst my/home
  (eval-when-compile
    (file-name-directory
     (file-chase-links (or load-file-name "~/.emacs.d/init.el")))))
```

The variable `my/home` will be compiled to "~/.emacs.d/" but `my/org` will not be evaluated in byte-compilation unless I rewrite it as

```
(defconst my/org (eval-when-compile (setup-defaults "org")))
```

So, do I need to do that for all my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, nevermind I see that this is what macros are for, just use `defmacro` instead seems to solve the problem,

```
(defmacro setup-defaults (loc)
  (when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (cond
     ((file-exists-p (expand-file-name loc "~"))
      (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name loc "~")))
     ((file-exists-p (expand-file-name loc "d:/"))
      (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name loc "d:/"))))))
```